# R - replacement at random

Tags: r

The `sub` function in R is replacing the **first occurence** of a pattern.

Example:

```
> s <- "my name is sam"
> sub(" ","*",s)
[1] "my*name is sam"
```

However is there an easy way to replacement at a random position of the three spaces (" "):

```
"my*name is sam"
"my name is*sam"
"my name*is sam"
```

Comment: Do you know for sure that there will be three spaces when you use this?

Comment: The number of spaces is known! But there can be more @G5W

Comment: And are you selecting one of the first three at random or any blank at random?

Comment: The blanks at random @G5W

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution is provided here following. Briefly, you can split your sentence when a space is found. You use `sample()` to pick a random position and then replace the corresponding space with a character of your choice (*). 
Finally, you paste everything together.

```
s <- "my name is sam"

# get your words
elems <- strsplit(s, " ")[[1]]

# recreate the spaces between words. Add an extra "" to add after the last word 
spacer <- c(rep(" ", (length(elems)-1)), "") 

# pick a random 'space' and replace it to *
pos <- sample(1:(length(elems)-1), size = 1)
spacer[pos] <- "*"

# paste everything together
result <- paste(paste(elems, spacer, sep = "", collapse = ""), sep = "", collapse = "")
```

The result

```
result
"my name*is sam"
```

Run the same lines again a few times, the sampling is random, so you should get all three possible results...

Answer (score 1):

And using `stringr`:

```
library(stringr)
s <- "my name is sam"
index <- sample(str_locate_all(s, " ")[[1]][,1], 1)
str_sub(s, index, index) <- "*"
```

Answer (score 0):

A different solution.   Count the blanks and choose one to replace at random. Then construct a regular expression based on the randomly chosen spot. This code uses `str_count` from the stringr package.

```
library(stringr)
position = sample(1:str_count(s, ' '), 1) - 1
pattern = paste0("((\\S*\\s){", position, "}\\S*)\\s")
sub(pattern, "\\1*", s)
```

A note about the regular expression.  It skips the first `position` blanks (and all non-blanks) to replace just the one chosen at random.